# Prime or composite?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Factorials are very interesting to solve. How will you find that $2014!+1$ (where '$!$' means factorial) is prime or composite ?

Comment: According to this page it's a composite.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_prime

Comment: Try with Wilson's theorem:
$n$ is a prime if and only if $(n-1)! \equiv -1$ mod $n$ and notice that $n=2015=5\cdot13\cdot31$ so...

Comment: @GIANCANE and what should that tell us besides $2015\nmid2014!+1$?

Comment: that it's not prime by Wilson's theorem

Comment: @GIANCANE It only tells us that $2015$ is not prime.

Comment: you're right sorry I got confused :)

Comment: Thanx friends..

Comment: @GIANCANE Wilson's theroem is only for prime numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> *Prime or composite ?*

Composite. Its smallest prime factor is $1287007$.